# Getting miles from Geography Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, geocoding, distance, geo

I'm new to using the Geography datatype, but I've figured out how to use it to get a list of zipcodes from a point (in the stored procedure I just have the point as varchar and I provide it with the "Longitude Latitude") so that was great.

However, the next thing I need to be able to show is roughly the miles from the point. I've looked at several answers and couldn't find anything.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetZipCodesByDistance]
@point varchar(500),
@distance int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @geoPoint geography
set @geoPoint = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (' + @point + ')', 4326)
                           .STBuffer(@distance / 0.0006213712)
SELECT   zc.zip_id AS ZipId
        ,zc.zip_code AS ZipCodeId
        ,zc.zip_type AS ZipType
        ,zc.zip_city AS ZipCity
        ,zc.zip_utc AS ZipUtc
        ,zc.zip_dst AS ZipDst
        ,zc.zip_latitude AS ZipLatitude
        ,zc.zip_longitude AS ZipLongitude,
        (Geo.MakeValid()).STDistance(@geoPoint)
FROM zip_code zc
WHERE zc.Geo.STIntersects(@geoPoint) = 1
```

So, my question is... how do I get it to return miles from the point? I tried to add the column "(Geo.MakeValid()).STDistance(@geoPoint)" but it returns all zeros.

Thank you for your help!

AJ

Comment: so what is your problem? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't explicit, I've edited my post to have the question in there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + zc.zip_latitude
                                    + ' ' + zc.zip_longitude + ')'
                                 , 4326).STDistance(@geoPoint);
```

Comment: This got me very close, I had to convert the zip_latitude and zip_longitude to VARCHAR(50) and now the distance column shows up at "13489758.0063597" I tried dividing that with 1609.344, but the distance came back as 8382.31166576187 which is incorrect style. Any thoughts?

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever got me closer, but for some reason the Distance value from the stored procedure shows miles. However, it doesn't transfer over to the web app. Any ideas?

Comment: I dont understand that function `Geo.MakeValid()` is `Geo` one table field?

Answer (score 1):

I still did not understand what actually is your requirement. We have a similar requirement to find distance between zip codes. See a sample function that does the work

```
CREATE FUNCTION Wrk.ZipDistance
(
    @Zip1 VARCHAR(20)
    ,@Zip2 VARCHAR(20)
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LatLong1 GEOGRAPHY
    DECLARE @LatLong2 GEOGRAPHY
    DECLARE @Result FLOAT
    SELECT
        @LatLong1 = LatLong
    FROM
        PostalCode
    WHERE
        PostalCode = @Zip1

    SELECT
        @LatLong2 = LatLong
    FROM
        PostalCode
    WHERE
        PostalCode = @Zip2

    SELECT @Result = @Lat1.STDistance(@Lat2) 

    RETURN @Result/1000
END
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest introducing a separate variable to hold the *point* versus your buffered area:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetZipCodesByDistance]
@point varchar(500),
@distance int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @geoPoint geography
set @geoPoint = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (' + @point + ')', 4326);

declare @searchArea geography
set @searchArea = @geoPoint.STBuffer(@distance / 0.0006213712)

select  zc.zip_id AS ZipId
        ,zc.zip_code AS ZipCodeId
        ,zc.zip_type AS ZipType
        ,zc.zip_city AS ZipCity
        ,zc.zip_utc AS ZipUtc
        ,zc.zip_dst AS ZipDst
        ,zc.zip_latitude AS ZipLatitude
        ,zc.zip_longitude AS ZipLongitude,
        (Geo.MakeValid()).STDistance(@geoPoint)
        FROM zip_code zc
where zc.Geo.STIntersects(@searchArea) = 1
```

> I tried to add the column "(Geo.MakeValid()).STDistance(@geoPoint)" but it returns all zeros.

Previously you were computing the distance between the found points and the *search area* - which is of course 0 since we've already established (via `STIntersects`) that they're within the area. So I've changed things around so that the `STDistance` call is using the point rather than the area.

(Of course, I'd also recommend, if at all possible that the parameter of the stored procedure be changed so that you're passed an already constructed `geography` rather than a string. But that may not always be possible)

Comment: This works perfectly in SQL. However, when I call the stored procedure from the MVC app, it returns 0. In my model, I have: [NotMapped]
public double Distance { get; set; }. I changed the SQL query so that the last "column" is returned as Distance. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The very first bit of code you're showing me is the attribute `NotMapped`

Comment: Found something interesting. In the DbContext, I have the following: var query = this.Database.SqlQuery<ZipCode>(
                "GetZipCodesByDistance @point, @distance",
                new SqlParameter("point", point),
                new SqlParameter("distance", distance)
            );
            return query;

Which, while running it in debug more, I get the error: The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.

Comment: Here's the entire Facility class can be found here: https://gist.github.com/ajtatum/88ff2c3bd426e9c0f58fa290f3cf99ad

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured out a way to make this work.

The stored procedure looks like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetZipCodesByDistance] @point VARCHAR(500),
@distance INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @geoPoint GEOGRAPHY
SET @geoPoint = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT (' + @point + ')', 4326);

DECLARE @searchArea GEOGRAPHY
SET @searchArea = @geoPoint.STBuffer(@distance / 0.0006213712)

DECLARE @ZipDistance TABLE(
ZipCode VARCHAR(5),
ZipLatitude DECIMAL(9,6),
ZipLongitude DECIMAL(9,6),
Distance DECIMAL(9,2)
)

INSERT INTO @ZipDistance
SELECT
        zc.zip_code AS ZipCode
        ,zc.zip_latitude AS ZipLatitude
        ,zc.zip_longitude AS ZipLongitude
        ,CAST((((Geo.MakeValid()).STDistance(@geoPoint))/1609.34) AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS Distance
FROM zip_code zc
WHERE zc.Geo.STIntersects(@searchArea) = 1

SELECT * FROM @ZipDistance
END
```

Then I created a model:

```
public class ZipCodeWithDistance
{
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public decimal ZipLatitude { get; set; }
    public decimal ZipLongitude { get; set; }
    public decimal Distance { get; set; }
}
```

In the DbContext, I have the following:

```
public List<ZipCodeWithDistance> GetZipCodes(string point, int distance)
{
    var zipCodes = this.Database.SqlQuery<ZipCodeWithDistance>(
    "GetZipCodesByDistance @point, @distance",
    new SqlParameter("point", point),
    new SqlParameter("distance", distance)
    ).ToList();

    return zipCodes;
}
```

In the FacilityModel, I have:

```
[NotMapped]
public decimal Distance { get; set; }
```

Finally, in the Service, I have the following:

```
public IQueryable<Facility>GetFacilitiesByZipCodes(List<ZipCodeWithDistance> zipCodes)
{
    var zipCodeName = zipCodes.Select(x => x.ZipCode).ToList();
    var facilities = oandpDbContext.Facilities.Where(x => zipCodeName.Contains(x.ZipCode.Substring(0, 5))).ToList();
    facilities.ForEach(x =>
    {
        var zip = zipCodes.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ZipCode == x.ZipCode.Substring(0, 5));
        if (zip != null)
        {
            x.Distance = zip.Distance;
        }
    });
return facilities.AsQueryable();
}
```

Not sure if it's the best/most efficient way to get this done, but it works. Any thoughts or comments welcomed! Thank you, AJ